# A question on number theory.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $S$ be a finite set of positive integers. Assume that there are precisely $2023$ ordered
pairs $(x, y)$ in $S × S$ so that the product $ xy $ is a perfect square. Prove that one can
find at least four distinct elements in $  S$ so that none of their pairwise products is a
perfect square.

Note: As an example, if $S ≡(1, 2, 4) $, there are exactly five such ordered pairs: $(1, 1),
(1, 4), (2, 2), (4, 1), \text{and} (4, 4).$

**The question is from INMO 2023**

I first thought taking $44+87$ which have $ 44$ perfect square and other $87$ elements are not the square root of the $44 $ first numbers but are prime. This make $2023$ cases but how to prove "at least 4"?

Then I thought of writing all the elements which would make $2023$ such sets which I realized after 8 elements it became harder. I don't know how to prove in general.

Comment: I struggle to understand your last paragraph. Perhaps I misunderstood the problem? Check my answer please.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity (what do you mean "taking $44+45^2-44^2-2$..."?) but more importantly to reveal the source of the problem.  Problems involving the current year frequently appear in contests and competition problems.  Which contest is this taken from and when did it end?

Comment: That exam is taking place today, is it not?

Comment: @lulu yes. I gave it. I managed to solve 2 problems.

Comment: But aren't there still some people taking it?

Comment: @lulu there were 2 persons including me in the hall. The other one did nothing.

Comment: It's a national exam being given today...I thought a lot of people were taking it.  I could have that wrong, of course.  In any case, my understanding is that solutions will be posted tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let all prime numbers that can divide at least one item of $S$ be $p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_k$.

For each item $t$ in $S$, assign an array of length $k$ to it, so that the $i$th item is $\begin{cases}0,&2\mid\text V_{p_i}(t);\\1,&\rm otherwise.\end{cases}$ We can see that the product of $2$ items from $S$ is a perfect square iff their arrays are identical.

Let their be $m$ kinds of arrays in total, existing $c_1$, $c_2$, $\dots$, $c_m$ items having it respectively. So
$$\sum_{i=1}^mc_m^2=2023.$$Notice that a sqaure $\equiv0,1,4\pmod8$, and $2023\equiv7\pmod8$. So we need at least four squares to have a sum $2023$. Then $m\ge4$, meaning that there're at least $4$ kinds of arrays.

Take a number having each kind of array will do.

Comment: What is $V_{p_i}$ and what does it mean $2|V_{p_i}$

Comment: For prime $p$, $\text V_p(n)$ satisfies $p^{\text V_p(n)}\mid n$ but $p^{1+\text V_p(n)}\nmid n$. *So it is the power of prime factors $p$ in the factorization of $n$*. ${}\mid$ is simply "divisible". @Joey

Answer (score 0):

As another solution involving binary systems have been uploaded. I had an another approach by using set theory,

Define relation $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S$ for elements $(x,y)\Leftrightarrow x \mathbb{R} y \Rightarrow xy=t^2, t\in \mathbb{N}$

You can see $\mathbb{R}$ is an equivalence relation over $S$

Let us assume there are $m$ type of [Equivalence Classes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class).

Let us also assume that is each equivalence class there are $n_i$

element of $S$ for $i = 1, 2, ....., m$ from each

equivalence class we will get $n_i× n_i$
pairs. This implies,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^m n_i^2=2023≡7 \pmod8$$

As said by youthdoo, $ x^2 ≡ 0,1,4 \pmod8 \Rightarrow m\geq 4$

If we take one element from each of there at least $4$ equivalence class then we are done!

Comment: Great! The mathematical language is very concise.